# onclick still running even after it returns false

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I have an onclick form submission and my function returns false but the page still loads. Here is the code for the html page.

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="put">
<fieldset>
<h1>Order a pizza</h1>
<br />
<p id="alerts"> hello</p>
<p>Choose Your Size: </p>
<select id="selector">
  <option value="volvo">Small</option>
  <option value="saab">Mediam</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Large</option>
  <option value="audi">Party</option>
</select>
<fieldset>
<legend>How well cooked?</legend><br />
<input type="radio" id="r1" class="cookGroup" value="r1" /> Lightly Cooked <br /><br />
<input type="radio" id="r2" class="cookGroup" value="r2" /> Normal <br /><br />
<input type="radio" id="r3" class="cookGroup" value="r3" /> Extra cooked <br /><br />
</fieldset> 
<fieldset>
<legend>Choose toppings</legend><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="r1" class="rgroup" value="r1" /> Pepperoni <br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="r2" class="rgroup" value="r2" /> Green Pepper <br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="r3" class="rgroup" value="r3" /> Mushrooms <br /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="r3" class="rgroup" value="r3" /> Extra Cheese <br /><br />
</fieldset> 
<p> Special Instructions </p>
<textarea name="t1" id="t1" rows="30" cols="100"></textarea>
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="userID" id="userID" value="12">
<input type="submit" value="submit form" onclick="check()">
<input type="reset" value="reset form">
<br /> <br />
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my function. It is in an external javascript file. It keeps returning false but the form continues to submit. I have a nasty problem that i can't seem to put my finger on. Please Help.

```
function check(){
run = false;
return run;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onclick event must include "return":

onclick="return check();"

Then it will works.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your function to:

```
function check(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   run = false;
   return run;
}
```

To precent the default function which here is sending the form.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<form method="put">` to `<form method="put" onsubmit='return check();'>`
and

`<input type="submit" value="submit form" onclick="check()">` to `<input type="submit" value="submit form">`

The form will then be acted upon whether the check was successful or not.